# Why using @model when declaring and @Model when accessing model?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In a View, when we declare the datatype of the model we use :

```
@model SomeDatatype
```

But when accessing (for displaying purpose), we have to use

```
<div>@Model.SomeProperty</div>
```

Why this difference ? ('@M' and '@m'). 
I know MVC is "convention over configuration", but this bother me to not know why each time i'm writing @Model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically @model with small m are directive, where @Model with big M is actual property.

**Edit**

Add a little more explanation.  @model is really a syntax sugar way of defining the type of the Model pass in the view.

Use to, you will use @inhertis to do Model declaration, it is easier to use @model for defining strong type.

you can read more on : http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/asp-net-mvc-3-new-model-directive-support-in-razor

Answer (score 2):

One is used to declare the strong type that the `model` is, and the other is used to access the `model` itself.

Model is a variable, `@model` is a keyword saying what type `Model` will be.

```
@model YourProject.Models.XYZ
```

Above is a way to declare strongly type view.

Model is a `variable` of type `YourProject.Models.XYZ`